# Precision issues with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6, floating-point-precision

I have an application written in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0. Now I have rewritten the application in Visual Studio 2010 using C#,  but the results are not matching because of precision problems. One of such precision issues is the following one.

```
float a = 1.0f;

float b = 3.0f;

float c = a / b;
```

This is C# code when run in Visual studio 2010 gives `c` value = `0.333333343`

But the same code, removing f after the value in the value definition, when run on Visual C++ 6.0 gives c value = `0.333333`.

Can anybody sort it out and explain the way to have the same value for c in visual Studio as well as in Visual C++ 6.0??

---

Actually the values are taken from the watch window. I came to know that different versions of visual studio may differ in floating point format representation. Hence the values in watch may not be useful. This is the reason why I have printed the values in both visual studio versions and the results are as follows.
with visual studio 6.0 using visual c++ language it is 0.333333(six 3's)

but with visual studio 10 using C# language it is 0.3333333(seven 3's)

So can anybody help me to make my C# program to produce the same result as visual C++??? 
(i.e how can i make floating operations to produce the same results on both the versions???)

Comment: How are you looking at the values? I'm pretty sure the internal representation is the same (unless I'm mistaken and C# uses `double` behind the scenes), but the methods of showing a number to the user differ, so you could simply be looking at different display defaults.

Comment: @MrLister the C# 4.0 spec says in section 4.1.6 that a binary operation on floats "is performed using *at least* `float` range and precision" (emphasis added).  So the behind-the-scenes precision is implementation-defined.  The .NET Framework may well use doubles behind the scenes.

Answer (score 15):

Given that the exact value is 0.3 recurring, neither of them is "correct" - and if you're trying to match *exact* results of binary floating point calculations, that's generally a bad idea to start with due to the way they work. (See my article on [binary floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for some more information.)

It's *possible* that you shouldn't be using binary floating point in the first place (e.g. if your values represent exact, artificial amounts such as money). Alternatively, it's possible that you should only be doing equality comparisons with a particular tolerance.

It's *also* possible that C# and C are producing the exact same bit pattern - but you're seeing different results because of how those values are being *formatted*. Again, I wouldn't use the text representation of numbers for comparisons.

Comment: I have printed both the values, with visual C++ giving 0.333333(six 3's) and with C# giving 0.3333333(seven 3's).That means there is an error in that. How can I make Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual Studio 10 with C# produce the same results??

Comment: @Mahesh: No, it doesn't mean there's an error. I suspect it's just down to the text fornatting involved in each case.

Answer (score 5):

`C#` is simply displaying fewer decimal places. `0.333333343` rounded to six significant figures is `0.333333`. The underlying value of `c` is the same.

Of course, if you want more precision, you can always use `double` variables.

Answer (score 3):

C# floating point can be handled by `float` and `double` types. A `float` type has a precision of 7 digits and a `double` 16.

I believe that the C++ standard precision is around 16 digits (15.9 on average!).

In any case neither representation is arithmetically correct as 1/3 is 0.333 recurring.

I think that it's merely the representation of the value that you are seeing (be aware that the debugger will convert the value to a string for display. If you check the memory locations for each you'll probably find that the values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

A quick check reveals that yes, the numbers are exactly the same. So the answer to your question is, when you want the same output, all you need to do is make sure the display methods are compatible.
For instance, `printf("%9.7f", result)` in C and `string.Format("{0:0.0000000}", result)` in C#. That's all.